# Can we trust the results of PROC MIXED when the G matrix is not positive definite?

Tags: mixed-model, sas

PROC MIXED in SAS sometimes estimates a non-positive definite matrix of the random effects. However PROC MIXED nonetheless provides the estimates and the standard errors of the fixed effects in such a case. Can we consider that these estimates and standard errors are correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make valid inferences on the fixed effects as long as the matrix $\mathbf{V}$ is positive definite, where $\mathbf{V}$ is the variance/covariance matrix of the implied marginal model.

Remember to specify the option `nobound` in the `proc mixed` statement.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the $V$ matrix. Do you have a reference for your claim ? And why would I specify the nobound option ?

Comment: Yes, this is my reference: Linear Mixed Models - A Practical Guide Using Statistical Software (B.West, K.B.Welch and A.T.Galecki) Chapman & Hall/CRC. If the matrix is not positive definite because, for example, one variance is estimated to be negative and you don't specify the `nobound` option, that variance will be forced to be equal to 0.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But in my example there is no zero estimated variance.

Comment: andrea, do I have to use my hands to derive the $V$ matrix or is it possible to get it from SAS ?

Comment: Take a look at the option `V` of the `random` statement.

Comment: Excellent. And I have to use R to check the positive definiteness ? ;)

Comment: Uhm, I don't know if a SAS macro to check the positive definiteness  of a matrix actually exists. Certainly you can save the $V$ matrix using the `ods output` capabilities and then write your own SAS macro :)

Comment: I prefer to export the V matrix and check the positive definiteness with R :)

Comment: In fact andrea, did you already see an example where $V$ is not positive definite but SAS does not return an error message ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: sorry Stéphane, I completely missed your last comment. Anyway, I honestly don't check the positive definiteness of the $\mathbf{V}$ matrix every time I run a LMM (and get no error messages) :)